Issues setting up Multi Lingual Site created in XM cloud with next JS
I recently tried to add another language for my website created in XM cloud. I used the OOB script provided by Sitecore to add another language and have published the items in edge server as well.

But when I try to visit the site with the language code embedded at the end of the URL, it gives a 404 error. Is there anything that I have missed ? The added language was french-canada.

This can be because you have the added the language in Sitecore XM cloud but not configured it in the nextJS head application.
You need to add the language (fr-CA) in the next.config.js.
Shared sample below.
i18n:{
 locales:[
   'en',
   'fr-CA'
],

 defaultLocale: jssConfig.defaultLanguage,
 localeDetection:false,
}

Hope this helps!

In the  next.config.js file you need to add:
i18n: {
       locales: ['en', 'fr-CA','new languages'],
       
        defaultLocale: jssConfig.defaultLanguage,
      } 

and you also need to configure few other things on Vercel: https://www.getfishtank.com/insights/guide-to-implementing-multilingual-support-in-sitecore-xm-cloud

You will need to the add the language inside the next.config.js in order to solve 404 issue.

Once you make these changes, you will to trigger the build again for static file generation of the localized pages.
Hope this helps!!!
